# how to change the result of a map by another format React

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, get, moleculer

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I am currently making a request on postman (which works correctly)

My back

```
getPackIntegrations: {
   rest: "GET /:id/integrations",
   resource: {
        name: "/packs/${id}",
        scope: "webmessenger-integrations:get",
        },
        cache: false,
        handler: async function (ctx) {
            const res = await ctx.call("packs.get", {
                id: ctx.params.id,
                fields: "integrations",
                query: {
                    ...ctx.params.query,
                },
            });
            return res;
        },
    },
```

postman's response

```
integrations : [{integration : xxx, entity : aaa}, {integration : yyy, entity : aaa}, 
{integration : zzz, entity : aaa}, {integration : 111, entity : bbb}, {integration : 222, entity : bbb}]
```

and I would rather receive the following format

```
[{entity: aaa, integrations : [xxx, yyy, zzz]}, {entity:bbb, integrations: [111,222]}]
```

How can I fix this issue?

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is far from optimal, but should at least do the trick. If someone else wants to improve upon my answer, that would be great.

```
let tmp_arr = [];
let final_arr = [];

res.integrations.map(
    item => {
        if(!tmp_arr[item.entity]){
            tmp_arr[item.entity] = [];
        }

        tmp_arr[item.entity].push(item.integration);
    }
);

for(const [k,v] of Object.entries(tmp_arr)){
    final_arr.push(
        {entity: k, integrations: v}
    );
}
return final_arr;
```

Comment: great it works fine thank you for helping me !! I am all the same taker for an improvement